# netbeans remote php workflow

Tags: php, netbeans

I noticed a strange sync problem. I have my project setup as a remote project and everything works fine. I have it set to upload on save. However, if someone on my server is working on a file and saves it. I don't see this change in netbeans and I end up opening a older version of the file and overwriting my colleague's changes when I press save.

Is there a way to have netbeans check the remote server for the latest file before saving?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, NetBeans can not check the remote file automatically. It's just not set up to do that. Even if it were, you would still run into problems where you would clobber your colleague's changes, or he would clobber yours.

What you have is a basic version control problem, which is best solved by implementing one of the several version control systems out there (e.g., CVS, Subversion, Git, Mercurial, etc.) and then "building" your website out to the server from version control. Short of that, an imperfect solution would be to partition the files such that you are forbidden to edit files assigned to your colleague, and vice-versa.

NetBeans can download the file for you, but only when you tell it to by right-clicking on the file and choosing the *Download* command. This downloads the file whether it has been updated by someone else or not.